# Can't figure out why bootstrap column won't collapse

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a grid of 6 using two rows with columns and was trying to make it so when the screen resizes from large to small it rearranges from 3 to 2 to 1. But I can't seem to make that work, I could have sworn the last time I used bootstrap to do this it was working. What happens is as the screen resizes, the profiles start to overlap over each other. What I have tried to do is add a css line for each resolution and increase the width percentage which seems to work, but I feel like it's not a clean approach.

here is the code:

```
<!-- Spotlight -->
<section id="spotlight">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="card card-3">
          <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/man4.jpg">
           <h3>Xanthe</h3>
           <p>Inspired by the movie Tangled, Xanthe's goal was to grow her hair down to her ankles - but now wants to help cancer patients by donating her hair and raising funds to support the fight against cancer. Xanthe raised over $1,000 in honour of her
            cousin who is battling leukemia.
           </p>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="card card-3">
          <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/man4.jpg">
          <h3>Team Gary</h3>
          <p>Team Gary recently ran in the Mississauga Marathon to support their Grandfather, Father and Family member Gary who is currently fighting liver cancer. The team of 13 raised an incredible $4,455 in the fight against cancer. Way to go Team Gary!</p>
        </div>
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="card card-3">
          <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/man4.jpg">
          <h3>Johnny Blonde Kitchen</h3>
          <p>This year they were very excited to be opening a storefront location. They raised $1,300 by fundraising online, and donating 10% of sales from opening day. In addition to fundraising, Jonny cut off his famous locks and donated several inches
            to Locks Of Love. We are so excited to have them be a part of our CCS family!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="card card-3">
          <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/man4.jpg">
          <h3>Brevitas Consulting</h3>
          <p>Brevitas Consulting takes on Breast Cancer Awareness Month each October with a walk-a-thon held one weekend during October bringing together their team in a fun, uplifting event. Thank you Brevitas!
          </p>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="card card-3">
          <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/man4.jpg">
          <h3>Irudaya</h3>
          <p>These talented young women created and executed a two hour dance production; Journey: A Glimpse Into Tamil Cinema. With the Society being one of their charities of choice, these dancers raised $10,000 for the fight against cancer! Amazing work!</p>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="card card-3">
          <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/man4.jpg">
          <h3>Maureen Parent</h3>
          <p>Maureen is a breast cancer survivor who is dedicate to raising funds for cancer research. In 10 years she has raised over $85,000 with an annual pasta dinner and has her sights set on raising $1,000,000 for the fight against breast cancer.</p>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
         <div class="addPad">
          <p>Be a cancer fighter &nbsp; <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-padin" id="hideshow2">Get Started</a></p>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Spotlight -->
<section id="spotlight">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card card-3">
            <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/man4.jpg">
            <h3>Xanthe</h3>
            <p>Inspired by the movie Tangled, Xanthe's goal was to grow her hair down to her ankles - but now wants to help cancer patients by donating her hair and raising funds to support the fight against cancer. Xanthe raised over $1,000 in honour of
              her cousin who is battling leukemia.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card card-3">
            <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/man4.jpg">
            <h3>Team Gary</h3>
            <p>Team Gary recently ran in the Mississauga Marathon to support their Grandfather, Father and Family member Gary who is currently fighting liver cancer. The team of 13 raised an incredible $4,455 in the fight against cancer. Way to go Team Gary!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card card-3">
            <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/man4.jpg">
            <h3>Johnny Blonde Kitchen</h3>
            <p>This year they were very excited to be opening a storefront location. They raised $1,300 by fundraising online, and donating 10% of sales from opening day. In addition to fundraising, Jonny cut off his famous locks and donated several inches
              to Locks Of Love. We are so excited to have them be a part of our CCS family!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card card-3">
            <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/man4.jpg">
            <h3>Brevitas Consulting</h3>
            <p>Brevitas Consulting takes on Breast Cancer Awareness Month each October with a walk-a-thon held one weekend during October bringing together their team in a fun, uplifting event. Thank you Brevitas!
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card card-3">
            <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/man4.jpg">
            <h3>Irudaya</h3>
            <p>These talented young women created and executed a two hour dance production; Journey: A Glimpse Into Tamil Cinema. With the Society being one of their charities of choice, these dancers raised $10,000 for the fight against cancer! Amazing
              work!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card card-3">
            <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/man4.jpg">
            <h3>Maureen Parent</h3>
            <p>Maureen is a breast cancer survivor who is dedicate to raising funds for cancer research. In 10 years she has raised over $85,000 with an annual pasta dinner and has her sights set on raising $1,000,000 for the fight against breast cancer.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="addPad">
              <p>Be a cancer fighter &nbsp; <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-padin" id="hideshow2">Get Started</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

to give you a better idea of what's happening here's a screenshot of when the screen reaches 991px

[image: screenshot]

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated! thanks for your time

**Update**
Restructured the HTML according to W3S, still gives me the same overlapping issue.

```
<section id="spotlight">
  <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="card card-3">
          <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/xanthe.jpg">
           <h3>Xanthe</h3>
           <p>  </p>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="card card-3">
          <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/TeamGary.jpg">
          <h3>Team Gary</h3>
          <p></p>
        </div>
       </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="card card-3">
          <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/Johnny.jpg">
          <h3>Johnny Blonde Kitchen</h3>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="card card-3">
          <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/Brevitas.jpg">
          <h3>Brevitas Consulting</h3>
          <p></p>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="card card-3">
          <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/irudaya.jpg">
          <h3>Irudaya</h3>
          <p></p>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="card card-3">
          <img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/img/spotlight/MaureenParent.jpg">
          <h3>Maureen Parent</h3>
          <p></p>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
         <div class="addPad">
          <p>Be a cancer fighter &nbsp; <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-padin" id="hideshow2">Get Started</a></p>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Does this happen as the width gets smaller? Also, what browser?

Comment: Also, if you're saying you've implemented custom CSS, you need to include that. Either way you need to be more specific as to whether the problem happens as the page/window is made wider or narrower.

Comment: @MattD sorry for late response internet got knocked out, Yes its as the screen width gets smaller, and it happens on all main browsers, IE, Firefox, and Chrome. The reason I didn't include the custom css is because I've removed it from being referenced, and it still happens. Instead of collapse from 3 to 2 to 1 it goes from 3 to overlapping each other to 1. So I'm confused

Comment: So on really narrow devices you want everything to be one column wide, two wide on the next step up, and three wide on the next step up and higher?

Comment: @MattD yes, exactly that.

Comment: You have columns nested without the requisite rows in between. I'd start there.

Comment: @isherwood I took a look at w3s and restructured according to how they have it but they still overlap, I've udpated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are the problem here. Add class="img-responsive" to the image tag and it should fix it for you. At a certain width, the image size gets bigger than the column width and hence it overlaps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I gave it a shot, removed any css img sizing and tried that out and it still happens. One thing I noticed is, as the window resizes the grid goes past the margin of the page until it collapses from 3 to 1, which is weird. I didn't notice that before, removed the `img-responsive` class and I see that it's still there, so I think I have some sort of layout issue with my whole page? its only that one section where it's happening though, nothing else is pushing off screen in desktop view as the window resizes.

Comment: @Umeed Here is the working fiddle with your code + class ="img-responsive" https://jsfiddle.net/mcad1jzh/ 

Looks like some other issue with your setup maybe.

Comment: Oh, so collapsing to 2 doesn't actually happen? so what's happening is right, and the images are resizing. Interesting, okay I'm going to try something out. Thanks King this helps a lot!

Comment: Yes! okay so with the img responsive class and resizing the profile css's it looks awesome now even if it doesn't collapse to 2 it fits on the screen cleanly! don't even need to mess with the cols. thanks King!

Comment: Great! And if you want to collapse it to different size columns, trying using bootstraps classes "col-lg-, col-md-, col-sm-, and col-xs-" for the target screensizes.